# Does Windows Server 2022 support Powershell Version 7?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2022

Does Windows Server 2022 support Powershell 7?

Based on what I've seen so far, it looks like it supports 5.0 out of the box.
I've googled around a bit and it looks like it's supported on Windows 10/11, Windows Server 2012, 201 and 2019.

It surprised me to not see Windows Server 2022 listed.

Comment: The information might not be totally up to date. You may simply try it. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Here you have a seemingly more up to date info [PowerShell Support Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/powershell-support-lifecycle?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @Olaf, Thanks, that's what I was looking for. It seems that it has PS 5.1 installed out of the box.

Comment: PowerShell Core will not replace Windows PowerShell in the near future. Windows operating systems will come with Windows PowerShell installed out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell 7 is supported in Windows Server 2022 as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3#supported-versions-of-windows), along the different install option.

| Windows | 7.2 (LTS-current) | 7.3 | 7.4 (preview) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows Server 2016, 2019, or 2022 | Supported | Supported | Supported |

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer your question from experience with Server 2022, I think I can safely say "Yes" to your question based on my experience with the downloadable [Zip version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3#zip) of PowerShell 7.x.

That downloadable version works on anything and everything Windows I've placed it on, including Windows PE!  Download it, unzip it, run the "pwsh.exe" file in it, and start testing your code!